# Can c11 compiler be installed on AIX 5.3?

Tags: aix

Is it feasible to install c11 c-compiler on AIX 5.3?  IBM documentation only refers to AIX 7.1 and higher being supported... but would it work if I attempt to install?

Answer (score 0):

No. AIX earlier than 7.1 is end of support. Upgrade the OS.

This is implied by the [xlclang announcement](https://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?subtype=ca&infotype=an&appname=iSource&supplier=897&letternum=ENUS218-567) requiring AIX 7.1 or later.

As to other compilers, a new enough GCC supports C11. May be some work to change over if your developers and build scripts expect xlc.

Comment: I understand that any AIX earlier than 7.1 is not supported. The question was not "is it supported?" but "can I do it on AIX 5.3 by adding whatever is necessary?"  It is not practical to upgrade the OS on this machine at this time.

Comment: I will not recommend an operating system that ended support 8 years ago. You are missing security updates as well as features.